# Body tracking using Azure Kinect in unity and mapping it onto an avatar

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, azurekinect

The Body tracking data has been successfully applied onto the avatar using the [Azure kinect body tracking samples - unity integration sdk](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Samples/tree/master/body-tracking-samples/sample_unity_bodytracking).

But the Avatar is Static and does not move in space. It mimics the point body i.e. all the body tracking is mapped onto to the Avatar but unlike the Point body it does not move in space. The movement is not mapped onto the Avatar.

Example: When I move with respect to the Kinect Device in real world, that movement is being mapped onto the Point body and can be seen moving in the Unity window. But the Avatar stays in position. (The leg movement can be seen on the Avatar but it does not move in space). (The Avatar has the script [Puppet Avatar](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Samples/blob/master/body-tracking-samples/sample_unity_bodytracking/Assets/Scripts/PuppetAvatar.cs) applied on it.)

How to get the Avatar moving similar to the point body?

I followed Me. Angus Antley's tutorial on azure kinect unity samples to recreate this.

I want to achieve something like [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=5-PddfUKJL8). Notice how the Avatar moves along with the point body.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the response so that it is helpful to other community members!

As per the suggestions given by ["Angus Antley"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1116357/the-avatar-is-not-moving-in-space-unlike-the-point)
Please try the example scene PuppetMaster that can be found under the Assets/Scenes folder, please do a fresh clone of the sample.

[image]